# Parallels 14 with macOS Mojave has extra volume mounted named "Install macOS Mojave"

Tags: install, parallels-desktop, mojave

I successfully installed macOS Mojave as a guest OS on Parallels 14.0.1. I installed by using the Parallels *Control Center*, choosing `File` > `New` > `Install Windows or another OS from a DVD or image file` > `Continue` (button) > `Install macOS Mojave.app` (auto-detected in my Applications folder, and shown by default) > `Continue` (button).

Within that guest OS, in the Finder, the sidebar shows an extra volume named `Install macOS Mojave`.

➥ What is this extra volume?

➥ How do I get rid of it? Will doing so cripple my VM?

[image]

It sounds suspiciously connected to the installer app.

Previous versions of Parallels had a nasty problem where it created a second file besides the usual .pvm file, required for operation -- so you might back up and restore the .pvm only to discover that without the second mystery file you could no longer use your virtual machine. Given that history, I'm very nervous about this mysterious extra volume and Parallels dependence on it leading to future total failure when moving to another computer.

No other volumes appear in the configuration panel `Hardware`. I have already successfully installed the `Parallel Tools` into this guest OS.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any additional hard disks shown in the VM's Configure → Hardware beside the .hdd or equivalent? Since it shows as an internal disk rather than a connected ISO, I guess you used the unattended install for a macOS VM? If so, did Parallels confirm the installation and configuration was complete and are Parallels Tools installed? Has the machine rebooted since macOS/tools were installed?

Comment: @grg I edited Question to supply more detail. No, the mystery volume does not appear in configuration > `Hardware`. No, I did not use a .ISO, I installed by letting Parallels automatically find and suggest the macOS installer app downloaded from the App Store. Yes, the installation completed normally, I set up fresh new macOS user when first run, and yes, I did successfully install the Parallel Tools utility within that new guest OS. And yes, I have rebooted multiple times. Even if I eject that mystery volume, it reappears when rebooting.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, and I'm sure you have clicked on it, but instead of USB & Bluetooth can you add screenshots of Hard Disk 1 and Hard Disk 2? I wouldn't have thought there should be two entries for Hard Disk